# workspace/ compile/ library issue in XCode 4.5 trying to integrate a Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, xcode4.5, box2d-iphone

first time posting and a newbie to iOS but have been struggling with a workspace/ compile/ library issue for the past couple weeks and while I like the learning adventure it's taken me on I'm just fed up and need help. I'm using XCode4.5

I'm trying to integrate a Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj file into my own workspace file with one other project file (test.xcodeproj) so that I can grab some of the cool slicing functionality from this examples project file that I found online and put it into my app. Seems like a simple request, no? I setup a workspace project so that I can import the whole Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj file and modify code if I need to from within the same workspace.

I have done the following:

- specified the proper User Header Search Path for my app build settings:
  /Users/xx/Desktop/Code/Box2D-Examples-master, **recursive yes** and
  always search user path set to **Yes**
- I've created a library file Slice.a from
  Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj and am confused/ having issues with "**compile
  sources**" and adding "**copy headers**" in that this seems to be a stupid
  manual process in Xcode for adding these files and even when I try and filter things like
  ".m" and select a bunch it either doesn't select all the files and so I recursively keep
  adding more files until I actually get drastically different numbers of .h and .m files. I
  do feel like this is kinda stupid on my part since I'm adding all
  these .m and .h files (more than 100) from the Box2D and Cocos2D packages but my
  "linker error" and "unknown symbol i386" error messages seem to need
  these files... Is there a better way?
- I've played around with various scheme settings and made sure that I 
  added the library (slice.a) within the build target of my app's
  scheme. Why am I able to add the Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj as an
  additional build target for my app along with the library (slice.a)?
  Is there a way to avoid using library files for this kind of thing?
- I have set the build settings in my library (slice.a) file to Skip
  Install = yes

ok, so having said all I feel like my major problems and lack of understanding is surrounding the compile sources and copy headers of my library and also wondering whether I'm doing something funky from my app files which attempts to call a class that is in the Box2DCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj file. Here's just a small sample and the only uncommented portion referencing the other project's classes. I was able to resolve these linker errors by adding the CCDirector.m into my library.

```
// Try to use CADisplayLink director
// if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];

CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
```

my error messages differ somewhat based on what source files are added but I can't seem to figure out a proper combination of source files in my library (slice.a) file to resolve it all and it definitely doesn't get past the linking stage of compile.

here's a sample of the error messages I get:

> _ccRemoveHDSuffixFromFile", referenced from:
>         -[CCTextureCache addImageAsync:target:selector:] in libSlice.a(CCTextureCache.o)
>         -[CCTextureCache addImage:] in libSlice.a(CCTextureCache.o)
>         -[CCTextureCache(PVRSupport) addPVRTCImage:bpp:hasAlpha:width:] in libSlice.a(CCTextureCache.o)
>         -[CCTextureCache(PVRSupport) addPVRImage:] in libSlice.a(CCTextureCache.o)   "_ccpLength", referenced from:
>         -[CCLayerGradient updateColor] in libSlice.a(CCLayer.o)   "_cocos2dVersion", referenced from:
>         -[CCDirector init] in libSlice.a(CCDirector.o)   "_gluLookAt", referenced from:
>         -[CCDirectorIOS setProjection:] in libSlice.a(CCDirectorIOS.o)
>         -[CCCamera locate] in libSlice.a(CCCamera.o)
>         -[CCGridBase set3DProjection] in libSlice.a(CCGrid.o)   "_gluPerspective", referenced from:
>         -[CCDirectorIOS setProjection:] in libSlice.a(CCDirectorIOS.o)
>         -[CCGridBase set3DProjection] in libSlice.a(CCGrid.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

for awhile I was painstakingly adding .m files one by one into my library file build phases so that I was addressing the errors I saw but this was taking way too long and not leading me down the right track and I still feel like I'm missing something obvious or an even more (general) easy way to do what I'm doing.

I know I've said a lot and I apologize but I am mainly looking for some insight about compiling, linking librairies, etc which hopefully will help me solve the issues I'm having. Any input on the mechanics of XCode are welcome since I'm really hoping to gain a deep understanding here.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a fan of this workaround but it's where I've decided to go forward from for the moment so I figured I'd post it. It's sorta simple in concept but not necessarily scalable so eventually I'll have to come up with something better. Help!

Rather than trying to add Box2D/ Cocos2D or in my case (Box2dCocos2DExamples.xcodeproj) as a library to my app I figured I would add my app as a library to a new workspace containing the Box2dCocos2D.xcodeproj file. I then realized that it's even simpler to just add my app's source files into this new workspace since there aren't too many and start from there by rearranging the workspace's appDelegate file. This is working well but only because I've given up on adding/ creating library files :(